# Unable to implement p2p chat using SignalR in Android

Tags: android, chat, signalr, p2p, signalr-hub

I have sucessfully implemented SignalR in my android application. and message broadcasting is also working fine. i want to implement p2p chat in my application using SignalR. i checked clients library in Asp.Net, i also tried Google but not getting required output. i checked SignalR, SignalA and SignalJ. i think SignalJ is useful but unable to resolve some library issue like **scala** and **akka** can anyone please help me. how can i implement p2p chat using SignalR in my android application? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you already have message broadcasting working (presumably using `Clients.All`), you should simply use something the `Clients.Client(connectionId)`, `Clients.User(userId)` or even `Clients.Group(groupName)` to specify which client(s) should receive the message. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#selectingclients

Comment: @halter73 : i am working on Android native application and i am using hubProxy.On("sendMessage", new HubOnDataCallback() {}) for message receive and hubProxy.Invoke("Send", args, callback) to send message. unable to find Clients method. How can i use Clients method in Android native app??

Comment: can you post your code ..?

Comment: @Ajay Could you please share some code or a sample application to integrate signalR into native android.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ajay: if you have implemented p2p in SignalR. Can you please share any demo. thanks :)

Comment: please see this answer, it might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65166406/5735993